# Поиск записей со смешанным набором символов в поле таблицы

Tags: mysql

Доброго всем времени суток. У меня задача найти записи в таблице MySQL у которых в одном поле встречаются и русские и английские символы. Как бы их вывести одним запросом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать что-то в духе

```
WHERE name REGEXP "[a-z]" and name REGEXP "[а-я]"
```

Почитайте про регулярные выражения

http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Pattern_matching.html
http://www.exlab.net/tools/sheets/regexp.html
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F